# SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Tags: python

I am working through some code for one of the modules in my degree and I am meeting this error:
**SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier on the line**: where it says

`while abs(term) > 1e−5*(abs(sum)+1e−4):`

Can anyone help me resolve my problem?

```
import matplotlib .pyplot as plt # for plotting
from math import cos

def f(x):
    """Sums Fourier series"""
    sum=0.0
    term =1.0
    n=1.0
    while abs(term) > 1e−5*(abs(sum)+1e−4):
        term=cos(n * x)/(n * n)
        sum=sum+term
        n = n + 2
    return sum

#####
    
n=40
g=[f((4* pi * i)/n) for i in range(0,n)]
# plotting
fig = plt.figure ()
ax = fig.add_axes ([0 ,0 ,1 ,1])
line = ax.plot(g)
plt.setp(line)
plt.show ()
```

The plan is to plot a graph of how f(x) varies for x between 0 and 4π

Comment: Those are U+2212 MINUS SIGN characters, not regular ASCII-range U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS.

Comment: And don't use `sum` as name - it's a built-in.

Comment: Looks like `-` in `1e-5` is not the ordinary `-`.

Comment: @buran: They're not trying to use `1e` as a variable name. They're trying to write scientific notation float literals.

Comment: @user2357112, corrected my comment. thanks

Answer (score 1):

After copy/paste your code, it seems that you are using the character `U+2212` "`−`" instead of `U+002d` "`-`".